# how to validate timestamp within range in postman?

Tags: timestamp, range, postman

I have setTimeout(function(){}, [8000]); in pre-request script

GET response ,timestamp varies within 10seconds

```
{"deviceId": null,
"deviceName": null,
"timestamp": "2021-04-08T22:28:26Z"
}
```

test case I have written

```
var current_timestamp = new Date();
current_timestamp.setSeconds(current_timestamp.getSeconds() - 9);

var current_timestamp1 = new Date();
current_timestamp1.setSeconds(current_timestamp1.getSeconds() - 8);


var current_timestamp3 = new Date();
current_timestamp3.setSeconds(current_timestamp3.getSeconds() - 15);

pm.test("Retrieve currentTimeStamp ", function(){    pm.expect(jsonData.items[0].timestamp).to.be.oneOf([current_timestamp.toISOString().split('.')[0] + 'Z',current_timestamp1.toISOString().split('.')[0] + 'Z']);
```

)];

above code works but I want something within
10 seconds range because response time is more I cannot keep on
adding items in the array
so I tried

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
var responseTime = jsonData.items[0].timestamp;
tests["Response time is acceptable"] = _.inRange(responseTime,       current_timestamp1.toISOString().split('.')[0], current_timestamp3.toISOString().split('.')[0]);
```

this does not work.Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let moment = require('moment');

pm.test("Check the timestamp range", function () {
    pm.expect(moment( "2021-04-08T22:28:26Z").isBetween("2021-02-08T22:28:26Z",  "2021-04-08T22:28:27Z")).to.be.true;
});
```

You can use the [moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/) library in the scripts sandbox.